# Same static analysis reports in both modules

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, static-analysis, checkstyle, pmd

I have android project that has 2 modules. In the project root i have a folder named tools that has gradle files and xml files for all my static analysis tasks. The problem is when i run the tasks the reports in both modules are the same which only belong to one of the modules. Any help how to fix this ?

pmd.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'pmd'
def reportsDir = "${project.buildDir}/reports"
check.dependsOn 'pmd'
task pmd(type: Pmd, group: 'Verification', description: 'Runs code pmd checks', dependsOn: "assembleDebug") {
    ignoreFailures = false
    ruleSetFiles = files("$project.rootDir/tools/rules-pmd.xml")
    ruleSets = []
    source 'src/main/java'
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/gen/**'
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
        xml {
            destination "$reportsDir/pmd/pmd.xml"
        }
        html {
            destination "$reportsDir/pmd/pmd.html"
        }
    }
}
```

checkstyle.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
dependencies {
    checkstyle 'com.puppycrawl.tools:checkstyle:6.5'
}
def reportsDir = "$project.buildDir/reports"
check.dependsOn 'checkstyle'
task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle, group: 'Verification', description: 'Runs code style checks') {
    configFile file("$project.rootDir/tools/rules-checkstyle.xml")
    source 'src'
    include '**/*.java'

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        xml {
            destination "$reportsDir/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml"
        }
    }
    classpath = files()
}
```

findbugs:

```
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
def reportsDir = "${project.buildDir}/reports"
check.dependsOn 'findbugs'
task findbugs(type: FindBugs, group: 'Verification', dependsOn: "assembleDebug") {
    ignoreFailures = false
    effort = "max"
    reportLevel = "high"
    excludeFilter = new File("$project.rootDir/tools/rules-findbugs.xml")
    classes = files("${buildDir}/intermediates/classes")
    source 'src/main/java'
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/gen/**'
    reports {
        xml.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
        xml {
            destination "$reportsDir/findbugs/findbugs.xml"
        }
    html {
        destination "$reportsDir/findbugs/findbugs.html"
    }
}
classpath = files()
}
```

both modules build.gradle at the bottom:

```
apply from: "$project.rootDir/tools/script-findbugs.gradle"
apply from: "$project.rootDir/tools/script-pmd.gradle"
apply from: "$project.rootDir/tools/script-check-style.gradle"
```

root build.gralde

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.3.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
        classpath "com.uber:infer-plugin:0.7.4"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

settings.gradle:

```
include ':sampleApp', ':usecases'
```

Comment: You should include the current configuration for the tools you are using for us to help you out.

Comment: i added the gradle files :)

Comment: what about the root build.gradle?

Comment: I see nothing wrong. The config as is should work. Maybe you are doing something wrong in one of your module build scripts.

Comment: something like what ?

Comment: When you say "both modules", which are your modules? Is there a settings.gradle file?

Comment: @ThomasJensen i added the settings.gradle file

Comment: It turns out that when i open the files from the 'Finder' files directory it works fine, but when i open it from android stuido, i think both files have the same reference.